# Fix existing media names with accents

Tags: posts

Today, I updated the version from a wordpress blog and migrate to another server. But, I noticed that most of the image names has accents/special characters in the name.

This make the browser doesn't show the images anymore.

Is there a plugin/function/command to sanitize all my existing media files, and update the image names in the posts too?

Comment: I think it is not a problem of Wordpress or browsers, It is a problem of your new server. You should contact with them. I'm sorry to say this but note that asking for plugin recomendation is offtopic in this site. Asking for functions/commands without show us the code you have tried, working or not, is also offtopic because your question can fall in the "do the job for me" format.

Comment: Note that changing file names will effectively spike 404 errors and harm SEO like hits from Google Images. Your issue is either with new server configuration or lossy migration process, too little detail to tell.

Comment: Yes, actually is my server that can't find the images anymore. But I would like to execute something that can rename my images and update the image names in the database.

Comment: Have you found something ? Searching the exact same thing..

Answer (score 0):

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/bea-sanitize-filename/
This solves it for you, sorry I m 8 years late but hey here is the answer ^^